# De Méré paradox. Show that throwing at least one "one" of 4 dice is more probable than throwing at least two "ones" of 24 tosses of a dice.

Tags: probability

De Méré paradox. Show that throwing at least one "one" of 4 dice is more probable than throwing at least two "ones" of 24 tosses of a dice. Finding the probability of the first is easy : $P(A)=1-({5\over6})^4.$ Having trouble with the second..

Since the following question is in the same group. I think it's best i post it too here.A coin is trown ten times. What is the probability of "tails" showing up at least 5 times. What I am having trouble with is the "at least" type of questions..

Comment: You’ve misstated the second version: it should be the probability of getting at least one *pair* of $1$s in $24$ rolls of a *pair* of dice.

Comment: Say the question were like this, the official is doable(i understand how to find what you say), what i am interested in is the at least $x$ times an outcome , which i need clarification on how to solve. I gave two examples, i'd much appreciate if someone could explain how they are solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question as stated, calculate the probability $p_0$ of getting no $1$s in $24$ rolls and the probability $p_1$ of getting exactly one $1$ in $24$ rolls; the desired probability is then $1-p_0-p_1$. In calculating $p_1$ don’t forget that the $1$ can occur on any of the $24$ rolls.

The coin question can be done similarly: calculate the probabilities $p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3$, and $p_4$ of getting exactly $0,1,2,3$, or $4$ tails; you want $1-p_0-p_1-p_2-p_3-p_4$. This is rather tedious, though, and with a bit of cleverness we can greatly reduce the amount of calculation required. Let $p_T$ be the probability of getting more tails than heads, $p_H$ the probability of getting more heads than tails, and $p_E$ the probability of getting $5$ of each. Then $p_T=p_H$, so $2p_T+p_E=1$. The desired probability is $p_T+p_E$ (why?), which you can get by calculating $p_E$, then using the equation $2p_T+p_E=1$ to get $p_T$, and adding the two.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering the corrected version of the problem, thanks to Brian M. Scott.)

Probability of throwing at least one *one* in four dice: inverse of the probability of throwing no *one*, which is $1-\left(\frac 5 6 \right)^4 \approx 0.51$, as you stated correctly.

Probability of throwing at least one pair of *ones* in 24 rolls of a pair of dice: it is known that the probability of getting $(1,1)$ when rolling a pair of dice is $\frac 1 {36}$. The probability of throwing at least one pair is the inverse of throwing no pairs at all, so $1-P($no pair of ones$)$.

We can find $P($no pair of ones$)$ since the variable is binomially distributed:

$$P(X=0) = {24 \choose 0}\left(1-\frac{1}{36}\right)^{24}\left(\frac 1 {36}\right)^0 = \left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^{24} \approx 0.5$$

And $0.51 > 0.5$ whereby the first is more likely than the second.

(I leave the coins-addendum to Brian's already-posted answer.)